# jQuery array validation

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to accept number from 10 to 50 along with 'AB' and 'NF'-

Following code accepts 0 to any number along with 'AB' and 'NF'

```
  <script>
        $.validator.addMethod("custom_number", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || value == "AB" || value == "NF" || 
                value.match(/^[0-9,\+-]+$/);
        }, "Please enter a valid number, or 'AB'");

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    'hd[]': {
                        required: false,
                        custom_number: true   
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<` and `>`:

```
this.optional(element) || value == "AB" || value == "NF" || 
            || (value < 50 && value > 10);
```

Or in a regex:

```
this.optional(element) || value.match(/^[1-5][0-9]|AB|NF$/);
```

`[1-5][0-9]|AB|NF` means: match `[1-5][0-9]` (10 - 50) OR `AB` OR `NF`. The `^...$` make sure the regex only matches when there are no other characters before or after the match (e.g. `fooNFbar`)